# Sort() function: How does JS compiler know what A and B is?

Tags: javascript, sorting

Heres an example:

```
var arr = [1,13,39,33]; arr.sort(function(a,b) { return a - b });
```

I understand how the algorithm works, but how does JS compiler know what **A** and **B** parameter is?

Comment: It loops over the array

Comment: Sidenote: arr.sort modifies the array. There's no need to reassign it like `arr = arr.sort(...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an untyped language and we don't know anything about what A and B is until runtime. Your example works on assumption that sorted array contains only numerical values. Consider following code:

```
var arr = ["d", "c", "b", "a"]
var comparator = function(a,b){return a-b}
var comparator2 = function(a,b){return a < b ? -1 : a == b ? 0 : 1 }

console.log(arr.sort(comparator))
console.log(arr.sort(comparator2))
```

First comparator is broken because subtraction for strings doesn't make sense, however `comparator2` works for any types supporting `<` operator.

Answer (score 1):

That is an anonymous or lambda function. It is a common pattern in many languages. the sort() method expects as a parameter a function that takes two parameters itself. You can write your function with two parameters and the sort() function will be the one to call yours with the two parameters.

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

If you are familiar with the `forEach` method on arrays, it is the same idea. In JS, you can iterate through an array, using

```
[5,3,1,3].forEach(function(val){
  console.log(val);
  // prints 5,3,1,3
});
```

So a similar question would be, how does JS know what `val` is in each iteration? Here is what it looks like to implement our own version of `forEach`:

```
Array.prototype.forEach = function(cb) {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    var item = this[i];
    cb(item);
  }
};
```

As you can see, the `forEach` method accepts a callback function as its only input, and then that callback is passed each value of the array, one at a time. It is the same idea with `sort()`.

Answer (score 1):

This is how the functions is defined (sort of just for understanding).

```
Array.prototype.sort2 = function(sortFunction){
    //this == the array.
    var result temp;
    for(var i = 0; i < this.length-1; i++){
       result = sortFunction(this[i], this[i+1]);
       if(result < 0){
          temp = this[i+1]; //if larger than 0 or equal it means the order is correct
          this[i+1] = this[i];
          this[i] = temp;
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your anonymous function here (the one with the A and B) is actually a parameter to sort.  Sort uses that function to determine if one element of you array is "smaller" or "should come first" when it is sorting your array.

With something like numbers it's pretty straightforward.  But what about some custom objects you have?  Say you have some project objects which contain the name of the responsible person and how much time is left on the project.  Now you need to sort first by the person's name, then by time left.  "First-ness" isn't so straightforward any more.  So you make a function that determines which order comes first, given any 2 of the things in your array.  Sort calls that function to determine "first-ness".